# MailChimp for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, email, checkbox, mailchimp

MailChimp for WordPress,i add country dropdown, email , firstname , last name and check box. i am getting all values expect mail chimp checkbox value.not getting checkbox values in mail chimp. please help me

```html
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
 #mc_embed_signup{background:#DCDBDB;padding:12px;clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
 /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
    We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">

    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
 
<div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
 <label for="mce-MMERGE3">Country  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
 <select name="MMERGE3" class="required" id="mce-MMERGE3">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Albania">Albania</option>
<option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
<option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
<option value="Angola">Angola</option>
<option value="Antigua &amp; Deps">Antigua &amp; Deps</option>
<option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
<option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
<option value="Australia">Australia</option>
<option value="Austria">Austria</option>
<option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
<option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
<option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
<option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
<option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
<option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
<option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
<option value="Belize">Belize</option>
<option value="Benin">Benin</option>
<option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
<option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
<option value="Bosnia Herzegovina">Bosnia Herzegovina</option>
<option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
<option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
<option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
<option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
<option value="Burkina">Burkina</option>
<option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
<option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
<option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
<option value="Canada">Canada</option>
<option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
<option value="Central African Rep">Central African Rep</option>
<option value="Chad">Chad</option>
<option value="Chile">Chile</option>
<option value="China">China</option>
<option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
<option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
<option value="Congo">Congo</option>
<option value="Congo {Democratic Rep}&quot;">Congo {Democratic Rep}&quot;</option>
<option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
<option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
<option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
<option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
<option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
<option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
<option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
<option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
<option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
<option value="East Timor">East Timor</option>
<option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
<option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
<option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
<option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
<option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
<option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
<option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
<option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
<option value="Finland">Finland</option>
<option value="France">France</option>
<option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
<option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
<option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
<option value="Germany">Germany</option>
<option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
<option value="Greece">Greece</option>
<option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
<option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
<option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
<option value="Guinea-Bissau">Guinea-Bissau</option>
<option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
<option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
<option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
<option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
<option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
<option value="India">India</option>
<option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
<option value="Iran">Iran</option>
<option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
<option value="Ireland {Republic}">Ireland {Republic}</option>
<option value="Israel">Israel</option>
<option value="Italy">Italy</option>
<option value="Ivory Coast">Ivory Coast</option>
<option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
<option value="Japan">Japan</option>
<option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
<option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
<option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
<option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
<option value="Korea North">Korea North</option>
<option value="Korea South">Korea South</option>
<option value="Kosovo">Kosovo</option>
<option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
<option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
<option value="Laos">Laos</option>
<option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
<option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
<option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
<option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
<option value="Libya">Libya</option>
<option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
<option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
<option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
<option value="Macedonia">Macedonia</option>
<option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
<option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
<option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
<option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
<option value="Mali">Mali</option>
<option value="Malta">Malta</option>
<option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
<option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
<option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
<option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
<option value="Micronesia">Micronesia</option>
<option value="Moldova">Moldova</option>
<option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
<option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
<option value="Montenegro">Montenegro</option>
<option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
<option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
<option value="Myanmar, {Burma}">Myanmar, {Burma}</option>
<option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
<option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
<option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
<option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
<option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
<option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
<option value="Niger">Niger</option>
<option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
<option value="Norway">Norway</option>
<option value="Oman">Oman</option>
<option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
<option value="Palau">Palau</option>
<option value="Panama">Panama</option>
<option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
<option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
<option value="Peru">Peru</option>
<option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
<option value="Poland">Poland</option>
<option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
<option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
<option value="Romania">Romania</option>
<option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option>
<option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
<option value="St Kitts &amp; Nevis">St Kitts &amp; Nevis</option>
<option value="St Lucia">St Lucia</option>
<option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
<option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
<option value="Saint Vincent &amp; the Grenadines&quot;">Saint Vincent &amp; the Grenadines&quot;</option>
<option value="Sao Tome &amp; Principe">Sao Tome &amp; Principe</option>
<option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
<option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
<option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
<option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
<option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
<option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
<option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
<option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
<option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
<option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
<option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
<option value="South Sudan">South Sudan</option>
<option value="Spain">Spain</option>
<option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
<option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
<option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
<option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
<option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
<option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
<option value="Syria">Syria</option>
<option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
<option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
<option value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option>
<option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
<option value="Togo">Togo</option>
<option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
<option value="Trinidad &amp; Tobago">Trinidad &amp; Tobago</option>
<option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
<option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
<option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
<option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
<option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
<option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
<option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
<option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="United States">United States</option>
<option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
<option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
<option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
<option value="Vatican City">Vatican City</option>
<option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
<option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
<option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
<option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
<option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>

 </select>
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
 <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
 <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
 <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
 <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
 <label for="mce-LNAME">Last Name  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
 <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="required" id="mce-LNAME">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group input-group">
    <strong>Are you interest in becoming a YEVO </strong>
    <ul><li><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group[14541][1]" id="mce-group[14541]-14541-0"><label for="mce-group[14541]-14541-0">Customer</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="group[14541][2]" id="mce-group[14541]-14541-1"><label for="mce-group[14541]-14541-1">Distributor</label></li>
</ul>
</div>
 <div id="mce-responses" class="">
  <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
  <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
 </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_3f442760e3efa05a80aa1d283_c2bc1c3291" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Join and Bring Yevo to your country!" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>

</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[3]='MMERGE3';ftypes[3]='dropdown';fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

box values

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the [MailChimp for WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/)? If so, please generate the checkbox field for your groupings using the **Add MailChimp field** tool generated on the right side of the screen when editing a form.

[image: Add field form in action]

This will make sure your form consists of the correct HTML so that fields are sent to MailChimp. :-)

Hope that helps!